# How do I combine a UITableView w/ another Section(uilabels and uibuttons) so all content scrolls

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uicontainerview

[image: This is one picture of the layout I am building. The orange line marks the beginning of the tableview. In this screen, each picture represents a different table cell.]

Here is what I need for the design.

1. The page content needs to auto-expand (at the bottom) depending on the size of the tableview.
2. All the page content needs to scroll together...as opposed to just the TableView scrolling and the scrolled tableview content going behind the top section of the page.

---

The approaches I have tried:

1. Using a container for the top section and tableview for the bottom section. Problem: the container stays still while TableContent scrolls.
2. (after 1. failed) Using a container(for the section above orange line) and tableview for bottom content all inside a UIScrollView. Problem: there was still overlap from container and tableview and not everything scrolled together.

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way to go about this ??

Thank you so much! Appreciate any help in advance.Of course if you give me the right answer, I will mark you as correct and give you good feedback
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this trouble, one way to solve this problem is by following this tutorial: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-headers-footers-table-view-ios7

In summary:

1. under the attribute inspector of table view, add one more prototype cell.

[image]

2.
In the attribute inspector of the header cell make sure to add an Identifier. In my case it was called *HistoryHeaderCell*

[image]

3.
Add any UI components - buttons, labels etc and any constraints to this view cell

4. In your tableViewController code add the following built-in function

**override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?** {}

... my full function looks like this:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      let  headerCell =   tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HistoryHeaderCell") as!  HistoryHeaderCell
      self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerCell;
      return headerCell
```

}
Note... the line **self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerCell;** is so that the header cell moves when the tableView is scrolled!  Hope this comes of use to someone :)